# How to read the attribute of an element xml in C# Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1, rss, rss-reader

I developing an app that can read rss, I set a class like that

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("enclosure")]
    public string enclosure { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pubDate")]
    public string pubDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string link { get; set; }
}
```

Howerver, the item returns that

```
<item>
<title>
Colombia 2-1 Paraguay: James Rodriguez and Carlos Bacca score as Jose Pekerman's side reach Copa America quarter-finals
</title>
<link>
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-3630657/Colombia-2-1-Paraguay-James-Rodriguez-Carlos-Bacca-score-Jose-Pekerman-s-reach-Copa-America-quarter-finals.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490
</link>
<description>
James Rodriguez scored a goal and set up another as Colombia became the first team to clinch a place in the Copa America quarter-finals. The Real Madrid provided the assist for Carlos Bacca's opener.
</description>
<enclosure url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/06/08/05/350A4D8200000578-0-image-a-63_1465360921756.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="84507" />
<pubDate>Wed, 08 Jun 2016 06:32:45 +0100</pubDate>
<guid>
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-3630657/Colombia-2-1-Paraguay-James-Rodriguez-Carlos-Bacca-score-Jose-Pekerman-s-reach-Copa-America-quarter-finals.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490
</guid>
</item>
```

So, it is clearly that the "enclosure" element return empty string, so how to read the "url" attribute of this "enclosure" tag by giving the annotation like above class, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write separate class for enclosure

```
     public class Item
        {
            [XmlElement("title")]
            public string title { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("description")]
            public string description { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("enclosure")]
            public Enclosure enclosure { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("pubDate")]
            public string pubDate { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("link")]
            public string link { get; set; }
        }

    public class Enclosure 
    {
        [XmlAttribute("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    //if enclosure has any child elements it comes under XmlElement like this
    // [XmlElement("enclosurechildelement")]
    // public string enclosurechildelement { get; set; }


    }
```